# Equivalent procedure to Scikit-Learns class_weight=balanced in Keras?

Tags: scikit-learn, cnn, svm, class-imbalance

I want to train a SVM and a CNN with the same unbalanced multiclass-dataset and want to compare the results.

I use Scikit-Learn for the SVM and Keras for the CNN.
My goal is that no class is preferred during the training, every class should be considered equally important.
For the SVM I use `class_weight='balanced'`.
Would it make sense to use also Scikit-Learns `class_weight='balanced'`
in Keras for training the CNN?

What is your opinion? What would you recommend?
Many thanks for every hint